# How can I access My Photostream from a my Macbook pro?

Tags: macos, photos, photo-stream

How can I access My Photostream from a my Macbook pro? I'm running El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

- Open system preferences and sign in to iCloud
- open photos and opt in to Photo Stream

You can get help from the help menu searching for Photo Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Photos app and click on *My Photo Stream* in the sidebar under *Photos*. If you don't see *My Photo Stream*, choose Photos>Preferences menu, and make sure you've checked the option for *My Photo Stream* (note this option is unavailable if you have checked the *iCloud Photos* option).

If you've checked *My Photo Stream* and you *don't* see *My Photo Stream* in the sidebar, try temporarily checking *iCloud Photos*, closing the preferences dialog, then going back and unchecking it later. How much later? I waited until the "Updating" message went away. This worked for me with macOS 11.6.